# Is it possible to do pattern matching in if conditional for github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm currently doing this:

```yaml
if: failure() && (github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/mybranch')
```

But we're using git flow (much to my chagrin).

**How could I check if the branch name contains a specific pattern?**

Something like this:

```yaml
if: failure() && ( !(github.ref ~= 'feature/*' )
```

Comment: Azure pipelines (same infrastructure) has a `startsWith` function... `startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/feature/')`.I suspect it may work here too...

Comment: @jessehouwing so I just tried this, and it's saying my pipeline isn't valid `if: failure() && !( contains( github.ref, "develop" ))`

Comment: There is no regex for `if` conditionals yet, but one solution is to do the regex pattern matching in a previous step and check the result in an `if` conditional. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58862864/github-actions-ci-conditional-regex/58869470#58869470) for an example.

Answer (score 5):

[`contains`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contains) appears to be as good as it gets

```
        if: failure() && !contains( github.ref, 'feature' )
```

Comment: This link might be better reference for available functions https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains